# The command echo "users" | ssh myserv does not return anything.. Why?

Tags: ssh

The command `echo "hostname" | ssh myserv` returns the hostname, but `echo "users" | ssh myserv` does not return anything?

When I ssh on the server then run the command `users`, it returns my user name (since I'm connected on it :-' ).

Answer (score 4):

`users` only shows users who are logged into a terminal (as recorded in `utmp`). `echo users | ssh myserv` doesn't create a terminal (it's not an interactive session), so that session isn't listed. The more common `ssh myserv users` similarly executes the command without creating a terminal. On the other hand, `ssh -t myserv users` (where `-t` forces a terminal to be created) should show you.

Compare also `ssh -t myserv 'tty; who'` (shows you logged in on that tty) with `ssh myserv 'tty; who'` (`not a tty`).

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
ssh myserv users
```

Answer (score 1):

I get an error when I attempt this.  Some programs require a tty.  Also keep in mind that who, and users are a special case, they are looking specifically at login sessions.

```
# echo users | ssh host
stdin: is not a tty
```

See:

man sshd_config

> **UseLogin** Specifies whether login(1) is used for interactive login sessions.  The default is “no”.  **Note that login(1) is never used for remote command execution**.

man users

> users  -  print the user names of users **currently logged in**